# Regex of exact length that matches specific group of numbers

Tags: regex

I'm looking to build a regex that matches the following group of numbers:

```
10xxxxxxx 
1116xxxxx 
143xxxxxx
146xxxxxx 
149xxxxxx
159xxxxxx
16xxxxxxx
```

(note the length is always 9)

where x is any digit. My best attempt yielded this:

```
/^1[01456][1369]*[6]*[0-9]$/
```

However, I can't get the length of the string to always be 9. Any ideas?

Edit: Maybe I wasn't clear enough, it needs to match those 7 cases, and ONLY those, inclusively and exclusively.

Comment: A crude, but working way is to replace every `x` with `\d`, join with `|` and wrap in `^(...)$`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
^1(?:[06]\d{2}|116|4[369]\d|59\d)\d{5}$
```

Comment: Most likely more efficient than mine (+1), but it seems a little over-complicated to think about (i.e. if another programmer took over and had to modify the valid numbers).

Answer (score 1):

use this pattern

```
^1[01456](16|3\d|6\d|9\d|\d\d)\d{5}$
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
^(?=[0-9]{9}$)(?:10|1116|143|146|149|159|16)
```

[***Demo***](http://regex101.com/r/kR5qC8/1)

---

This starts by looking at the beginning of the string for exactly 9 digits using a positive lookahead anchored to the end of the string. Then we look for any of your 7 specific groups of numbers that the string can start with.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
/^1[01456][1369][0-9]{6}$/
```

Since 3 digits are already matched by first 3 patterns `1`, `[01456]` and `[1369]` so last one must match exact 6 characters to enforce it a 9 digit input.

Comment: This won't do, since it won't match 162000000. The 2 in that string the problem.

Comment: @ArcaneCraeda: Not sure how `^1[01456][1369][0-9]{6}$` can match `162000000` since 2 is not allowed as 3rd character.

Comment: [You can see this demo that it is not matching `162000000`](http://regex101.com/r/aD3hZ2/1)